# Trouble running bitcoin unit tests with test_bitcoin on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bitcoin-core-development, testing

From Bitcoin Core's [test directory](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/test) (`bitcoin/src/test`), the executable `test_bitcoin` is supposed to run the unit tests. When I run `test_bitcoin`, however, I get:

```
replication requires locking support
Test setup error: std::runtime_error: CDBEnv::MakeMock : Error 22 opening database environment.
```

How can I run `test_bitcoin`? I installed Bitcoin from source.

**Also**:

I ran `configure` using the `--with-incompatible-bdb` flag.

Comment: Why don't you install the correct version of bdb? I have the correct .debs in this repository: https://github.com/nickodell/build_bitcoin Does that fix it?

Comment: @NickODell When I run `build.sh` I get: `dpkg: regarding .../libdb4.8-dev_4.8.24-1ubuntu1_i386.deb containing libdb4.8-dev:
 libdb5.3-dev conflicts with libdb4.8-dev
  libdb4.8-dev (version 4.8.24-1ubuntu1) is to be installed.
`

Comment: It's complaining that you already have a different version of libdb installed.

Comment: @NickODell I got it to work by uninstalling libdb5.3. I also had to reinstall the 64 bit version of libdb4.8-dev due to some packaging problem, but now it is working. Thanks! Also: how should this be written up as an answer so that users can see that this question already has been answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the correct version of BerkleyDB. (4.8) I have the correct .debs in this repository:

http://github.com/nickodell/build_bitcoin

You may need to uninstall the newer version of libdb first.